# JavaEE, Jboss, Empty string somewhere

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm really sorry, but I need to post below Java code. Which won't work although it is written in JAVA.

Please help me find that error, which is probably placed in line `lista.add...`, described as Empty string, parse error.

```
List<Pair<Place,TicketType>> lista = new LinkedList();
for ( String pair: request.getParameter("miejsca").split(" ") )
{
    lista.add(new Pair<Place,TicketType>(place_local.getPlace(Integer.parseInt(pair.split(":")[0].trim())),tt_local.getTicketType(Integer.parseInt(pair.split(":")[1].trim()))));
}
try
{
    reservation_local.addReservation(lista,id,m.getUser((String)session.getAttribute("name")).id);
}
catch (MySQLException e)
{
    out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you offended my religious feelings

Comment: Those comments do not fit the SO type of asking questions. And "*won't work although it is written in Java*" is nonsense (because it implies that you don't have programs with errors in Java). Note that it's Java not JAVA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you split the String in a separate step prior to the iteration. Also, validate that you really do receive the expected parameter from the HTTP request in the first place.